# Solr Running fine but am getting "SolrCore Initialization Failures" when i tried to open my console "localhost:8983"

Tags: configuration

I am using CentOs-6.7 (Installed Java latest version) and downloaded the `solr-5.3.2.tgz` from http://a.mbbsindia.com/lucene/solr/5.3.2/. Then i unziped to my directory 
`/opt/solr-5.3.2` and then i started solr using the command

> bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt

After that solr started fine without any issue and then i checked with port are listening fine and established.
Below my print after starting the solr.

```
 Welcome to the SolrCloud example!

Starting up 2 Solr nodes for your example SolrCloud cluster.

Creating Solr home directory /opt/solr-5.3.2/example/cloud/node1/solr
Cloning /opt/solr-5.3.2/example/cloud/node1 into
   /opt/solr-5.3.2/example/cloud/node2

Starting up Solr on port 8983 using command:
bin/solr start -cloud -p 8983 -s "example/cloud/node1/solr"

Waiting up to 30 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [\]
Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=8560). Happy searching!

Starting up Solr on port 7574 using command:
bin/solr start -cloud -p 7574 -s "example/cloud/node2/solr" -z localhost:9983

Waiting up to 30 seconds to see Solr running on port 7574 [\]
Started Solr server on port 7574 (pid=8776). Happy searching!

Connecting to ZooKeeper at localhost:9983 ...
Uploading /opt/solr-5.3.2/server/solr/configsets/data_driven_schema_configs/conf for config gettingstarted to ZooKeeper at localhost:9983

Creating new collection 'gettingstarted' using command:
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=gettingstarted&numShards=2&replicationFactor=2&maxShardsPerNode=2&collection.configName=gettingstarted

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":22130},
  "success":{"":{
      "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":20693},
      "core":"gettingstarted_shard2_replica2"}}}

Enabling auto soft-commits with maxTime 3 secs using the Config API

POSTing request to Config API: http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/config
{"set-property":{"updateHandler.autoSoftCommit.maxTime":"3000"}}
Successfully set-property updateHandler.autoSoftCommit.maxTime to 3000


SolrCloud example running, please visit: http://localhost:8983/solr
```

Now the problem is when i tried to open the solr console using http://localhost:8983/solr or http://localhost:8983, am getting the error

```
"SolrCore Initialization Failures"
```

and also getting connection lost.

**Note**: **Checklist**

Port are listening

cores are created using command

Restarted many times

Comment: Have you checked the certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the IP address in the firewall (e.g. iptables in CentOS machines). Once you configure the IP in that table, you are able to access the machine.